# Why curl_close in php7 does not work? There are many CLOSE_WAIT connections

Tags: php

I run below code in a php7 box, and use netstat I found 10 connections are in CLOSE_WAIT state. But when I run the same code in another php7 box, it's normal.

```
 <?php

for($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i){
        $ch = curl_init ();
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.baidu.com");
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_exec($ch);
        $return = curl_exec ( $ch );
        curl_close ( $ch );
        echo $i."\n\n";
}

sleep(10000);
```

The php7 and os version are exactly same. I think maybe there are some system parameters not configured correctly. Can you guys provide some tips to look into this?

Comment: Do both boxes have the same version of curl?

Comment: @jbsmoove  curl version on box 1 : curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.21 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2 .     curl version on box 2: curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate of [PHP CURL with proxy causes CLOSE_WAIT on socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899382/php-curl-with-proxy-causes-close-wait-on-socket/45156498)

tl;dr - Add 
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Connection: close"));`

Comment: Thanks. In fact, that question was answered by me :) . Walk around solution is add header, but I do not know the root cause for this.

Comment: Sound to me like the OS doesn't close the socket resource.